# Reading a file into an array Java

Tags: java

So I have a project in which I have to read book reference numbers and book titles from a .txt file into an array, and then a user is to enter a reference number that will do a search for the book with that reference number, so here is what i have, Keep in mind I'm not very experienced with java

```
public class Book {


ArrayList<String>  books = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = null;

 {
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BookList.txt"));
        String  book;
            while ((book = br.readLine()) != null) {
                books.add(book);
            }
     } catch (IOException e){
     } finally {
         try {
             br.close();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
         }
     }


    String [] bookList = new String[books.size()];
    books.toArray(bookList);


    }
}
```

That is to read the file into an array list, and then convert the array list into an array
Im not 100% sure if that's right so if theres a problem, I would gladly take your solution.

The problem i'm having is when i try to set up a method that allows a user to search

```
private void FindItActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
   String input;
   input = Input.getText();

   for(int i=0; i<bookList.length; i++){

   }


   }
```

I get an error that says cannot find symbol bookList, but im not sure what why

Thanks for any help or advice you may be able to offer

Comment: The variable's name is `books`, not `bookList`

Comment: He wants to use `bookList` (array of strings), not `books` (list of strings). He said right, but his problem is that `bookList` is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

your init code is inside a scoped brackets, you missed a method declaration by the way.

you cant reach bookList as its not a class parameter but declared in the scope.

put a method declaration (above the `try`) and add `bookList` declaration under your `BufferedReader` variable instead of declaring it in the scope.

Comment: That syntax is valid. It's just a block of code executed by every constructor. It still follows usual scoping rules, though...

Comment: It is not valid, he refers to non-static field - `books`

Comment: It's not a static initializer block (see how there's no "static" before the opening bracket?). It's perfectly valid. Try yourself.

Comment: You are right, it is valid. Sorry I oversight code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have bookList available to all of your methods

```
public class Book {
    ArrayList<String>  books = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] bookList;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    // ...
```

Then you need to set it to something.  Your current line `books.toArray(bookList);` uses bookList as the argument for toArray to know *what kind of array* it is producing, then it will return an array of that type. So you need to do

```
this.bookList = books.toArray(bookList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Book {

ArrayList<String>  books = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader br = null;
String[] bookList; //difference (bookList is now visible to all methods in class)
{
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("BookList.txt"));
        String  book;
            while ((book = br.readLine()) != null) {
                books.add(book);
            }
     } catch (IOException e){
     } finally {
         try {
             br.close();
         } catch (IOException ex) {
         }
     }
    bookList = new String[books.size()]; //difference
    books.toArray(bookList);
    }
}

private void FindItActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
   String input;
   input = Input.getText();

   for(int i=0; i<bookList.length; i++){
       //do something...
   }
}
```

Problem in your code is that you have tried to use variable `bookList` which was in different scope defined.

Comment: He is *not* using static initialization; it's right there, at the start of the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), "Initializing Instance Members".